# Issues with embedded mongoDB print/query

Tags: mongodb-query

I am trying to do a query that prints out all values of "x" that equal 2 in "initialSelected"

Values can look like this with different values of x and y

```
    "initialSelected" : {
            "x" : 2,
            "y" : 2
    }
```

I can get items to print with

db.main.find({ "initialSelected" : { "x" : 2, "y" : 2 } }).pretty()

But when I remove the "y" ..
db.main.find({ "initialSelected" : { "x" : 2 } }).pretty()

nothing will print

I thought about making the y value $lt and $gt 0 for all values of y since it seems it needs to be addressed, however the simple query below wouldn't print anything either.

db.main.find({ "initialSelected" : { "x" : 2, "y" : { $eq : 2 } } }).count()

What am I missing?  I am new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query of `db.main.find({ "initialSelected" : { "x" : 2 } })` will only match documents whose `initialSelected` field is an *exact* match to `{ x: 2 }` (i.e. no `y` field).

You need to use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field) to match just the `x` field:

```
db.main.find({ "initialSelected.x" : 2 })
```